# C# Simulate mouse inputs

Tags: c#, mouseevent, simulation, global, onmousedown

I'm developing an application that will help a handicapped person interact with the PC by simulating mouse inputs.

I've already achieved some progress but I have a challenge on **Mouse Left Drag**. I'd like the application to simulate Mouse Left Drag after 2 seconds on selecting "Mouse Left Drag" option and stop the drag 2 seconds after mouse stops moving. Here are some code that I'm working with:

```
  public partial class frmClicker : Form
  {
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);
    //Mouse actions
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x20;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x40;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = 0x01;
    private const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;

    public frmClicker()
    {
    ``InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void DoMouseLeftClick()
    {
      Thread.Sleep(defaultDelay);
      uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
      uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
      Thread.Sleep(defaultDelay);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }

    public void DoMouseLeftDoubleClick()
    {
      Thread.Sleep(defaultDelay);
      uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
      uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
      Thread.Sleep(defaultDelay);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
      Thread.Sleep(50);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }

    public void DoMouseLeftDrag()
    {
      Thread.Sleep(defaultDelay);
      uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
      uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
      Thread.Sleep(defaultDelay);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, X, Y, 0, 0);
      Thread.Sleep(dragRelease);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }

    public void DoMouseRightClick()
    {
      Thread.Sleep(defaultDelay);
      uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
      uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
      Thread.Sleep(defaultDelay);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }

    public void DoMouseRightDoubleClick()
    {
      Thread.Sleep(defaultDelay);
      uint X = (uint)Cursor.Position.X;
      uint Y = (uint)Cursor.Position.Y;
      Thread.Sleep(defaultDelay);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
      Thread.Sleep(50);
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
    }  
  }
```

Comment: all of your methods have `mouse_event(*DOWN | *UP ...` but the left drag that has `mouse_event(*DOWN | *DOWN ...`

Comment: @Viktor this implies that the mouse should click on mouse current position to indicate the drag start point, keep left mouse button until the point where it's released. Hope you got it.